# Facebook comments [link is unreachable]

Tags: facebook, parsing, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I was fixing a Facebook comment plugin for WordPress to solve this:

> Warning: [link] is unreachable.

After debugging I found `[og:link]` appearing several times, so I eliminated it. But now I am still facing the unreachable problem. Somebody told me it has something to do with [Open Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Open_Graph_protocol) in headers. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Pass your URL through the debugger tool at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and fix any errors it gives.

Comment: i did that already but keep getting:
Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/305418369522179), but without a resolution.